# Creating an Electron Application with Node.js Logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, get, electron

I've been practicing using Electron for a few months now, and I was wondering how to convert a Node.js webpage project that I made a while ago into an Electron app.  In my Node.js webpage, I used functions like

```
app.get('/' function(req, res){
    res.render('loginpage');
}
app.post('/loginCredentials', function(req, res){
    /*Make sure req.body.username and req.body.password are valid*/
    res.render('home');
}
```

Also in my Node.js application, whenever the user wants to see the database results, I query the database in the Node.js webpage and send the variables to the webpage when they're rendered.

But in Electron, I don't know how to handle such requests.If I wanted to make an Electron application, would I have to deal all of this in the webpage files themselves, or does Electron have some app.get/app.post methods?

Alternatively, is there a way to make my Node.js webpage load in a browser window like an Electron application?

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE 1; ipcMain Module function:**

In my electron main.js file, I have the following code:

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('hello', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg)
    event.returnValue = 'pong'
})
```

And in my webpage, that is located in the './views' directory, I have the following code: (it is a pug file and it renders correctly)

```
input(type ='submit', value ='Submit', onclick = "handleClick()")
...
script.  
    const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
    function handleClick(){    
        var x = ipcRenderer.sendSync('hello', 'ping')
        console.log(x) 
    }
```

I kept getting an error (it is shown at the bottom of the question) before made the following changes. I changed:

```
const ipcMain = require('electron')
```

to

```
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
```

Apparently, the brackets are required to be around the module for it to be imported correctly.

Error that existed but was fixed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ipcRenderer.sendSync is not a function
    at handleClick (loginpage.pug:64)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

ipcMain is a useful aspect in Electron that mimics the app.get/app.post in Node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is technically possible to make Node.js your backend for an Electron app, it would be a heavy handed solution and is not recommended.

Instead of post/get requests, instances of Electron's EventEmitter class are typically used for communicating between the front and backend. Use the `ipcMain` module on the backend, and `ipcRenderer` on your frontend to exchange any sort of data. In fact, messages can be sent either synchronously or asynchronously.

For example, from Electron's [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main):

```
// In main process.
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg)  // prints "ping"
  event.sender.send('asynchronous-reply', 'pong')
})

ipcMain.on('synchronous-message', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg)  // prints "ping"
  event.returnValue = 'pong'
})

// In renderer process (web page).
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
console.log(ipcRenderer.sendSync('synchronous-message', 'ping')) // prints "pong"

ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-reply', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints "pong"
})
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'ping')
```

Comment: I tried this method, but I keep getting an error. I put the details under Update 1 in the question

Comment: With Electron apps almost everything should go in the renderer. Your "backend" code should not be in the main process as not only is the wrong approach but you have all these IPC issues...

Comment: @Tim I had a single ipcMain issue, which was fixed because of a small error I made (I needed brackets around the module to import). Could you elaborate why ipcMain is the wrong approach?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with IPC. The Electron main process shouldn't however be used to host a backend. Almost all your code should be in the renderer